# can I get access to a unique pointer as const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a collection of unique_ptr objects to ms_order objects:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ms_order>> orders;
```

I want to make a private helper function to get ms_order objects:

```
const std::unique_ptr<ms_order>& ms_order_collection::get_order(const std::string &id) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ms_order>>::iterator it =
            std::find(orders.begin(), orders.end(),
                      [&id](const std::unique_ptr<ms_order>& op)
                      { return op->getId() == id; });
    return *it;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::unique_ptr<ms_order>' and 'const ms_order_collection::get_order(const string&)::<lambda(const std::unique_ptr<ms_order>&)>')
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The error makes no sense to me. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably wanted to use `std::find_if` rather than `std::find`. Otherwise, your code should work.

Comment: is ms_order::getId const qualified? As in void GetStuff() const; ?

Comment: @WhiZTiM Please make that an answer so we can vote.

Comment: @WhiZTiM that was it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) rather than [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

`std::find` compares each element in the given iterator range with the `value`. In your own case, the value you provided was a lambda object which is of an anonymous type that has no equivalence relation (or suitable `operator ==` ) with the type of the elements in `orders`

`std::find_if` calls your functor on each element, and returns the iterator position if `true`, else, an end iterator.